# git diff just the line numbers

Tags: git, ide

Something like which likes were `modified`, `added` or `removed`

```
--- a/src/app/codemirror/codeEditor.tsx
+++ b/src/app/codemirror/codeEditor.tsx
M 12
+ 72
+ 73
- 83
- 84
```

The basic objective is to get nice status highlights like e.g. Atom (or VsCode):

[image]

I've gone through https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I have gotten is `git diff -U0` i.e. Unified diff format with `0` spare lines. This generates output like:

[image]

Where each section `@@ -n1,n2 +n3,n4 @@` means that previously (`n1,n2`) the lines `n1 to n1+n2` are now lines `n3 to n3+n4`.

This means that

- if `n2` is zero then its all addition (Use `n3 to n3 + n4` to highlight)
- Else if `n4` is zero then its all deletion (Use `n3` to higlight)
- Else its modification (Use `n3` to highlight)

Comment: complicated! Why don't git make the math for us? What exactly does it mean in your image the number `-74,0`?

Comment: Note that in some cases when `n2` or `n4` are meant to be `0`, they and their comma are omitted. I haven't figured out what those cases specifically are yet.